# File Sharing a Routers Storage with Windows 10 requires SMB1 but

Tags: router, storage, sharing

can  SMB1 be added back into Windows 10 AGAIN after it uninstalled itself?

The net has NO searches for "downloading" SMB1 but lots of  ENABLES.
Can SMB1 be added back into Windows 10 for Router Storage sharing?

Having SHARED storage on my ROUTER to Windows 7/10 is more important than the risk.

Comment: SMBv1 can be indeed enabled on Windows 10.  However it is not recommended for obvious security concerns

Answer (score 1):

> The net has NO searches for "downloading" SMB1 but lots of ENABLES.

Since the SMB1 client and server are Windows components, "enabling" them will automatically download the required files through Windows Update. They never disappear from the component list entirely.